# Separate columns by sequential N rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, I need to separate these two columns (column A and B) by N sequential rows (for example 100 rows). so the output will be 100 rows in column A and B, another 100 rows in column C and D, .....is there a specific function can deal with this purpose?

Comment: It's not clear how columns can be separated by rows. Would you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: so the first column (column A) has 1000 rows, the second column (column B) also has 1000 rows. I want to separate these two columns into 20 new columns (each new column has 100 rows). it means row 1-100 as a new column, and row 101-200 as a new column and so on.  Does it make sense?

Comment: So it's actually *splitting* what you are after. Please **move the crucial details** from your last comment to the question, use the edit function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `n` always evenly divides the length of the frame, [`vsplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html#numpy-vsplit) + [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy-hstack) is an option:

```
n = 5
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(np.vsplit(df.values, len(df) // n)))
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda c: chr(c + ord('A')))
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(1, 16),
                   'B': np.arange(101, 116)})

n = 5
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(np.vsplit(df.values, len(df) // n)))
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda c: chr(c + ord('A')))
print(new_df)
```

```
     A    B
0    1  101
1    2  102
2    3  103
3    4  104
4    5  105
5    6  106
6    7  107
7    8  108
8    9  109
9   10  110
10  11  111
11  12  112
12  13  113
13  14  114
14  15  115
```

`new_df`:

```
   A    B   C    D   E    F
0  1  101   6  106  11  111
1  2  102   7  107  12  112
2  3  103   8  108  13  113
3  4  104   9  109  14  114
4  5  105  10  110  15  115
```

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 2001).reshape((-1, 2)), columns=["A", "B"])
print(df)

        A     B
0       1     2
1       3     4
2       5     6
3       7     8
4       9    10
..    ...   ...
995  1991  1992
996  1993  1994
997  1995  1996
998  1997  1998
999  1999  2000

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Use `np.array_split`

```
out = np.concatenate(np.array_split(df, range(100, len(df), 100)), axis=1)
print(out)

array([[   1,    2,  201, ..., 1602, 1801, 1802],
       [   3,    4,  203, ..., 1604, 1803, 1804],
       [   5,    6,  205, ..., 1606, 1805, 1806],
       ...,
       [ 195,  196,  395, ..., 1796, 1995, 1996],
       [ 197,  198,  397, ..., 1798, 1997, 1998],
       [ 199,  200,  399, ..., 1800, 1999, 2000]])
```

Build your dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=list(map(chr, range(65, out.shape[1]+65))))
print(df1)

      A    B    C    D    E    F  ...     O     P     Q     R     S     T
0     1    2  201  202  401  402  ...  1401  1402  1601  1602  1801  1802
1     3    4  203  204  403  404  ...  1403  1404  1603  1604  1803  1804
2     5    6  205  206  405  406  ...  1405  1406  1605  1606  1805  1806
3     7    8  207  208  407  408  ...  1407  1408  1607  1608  1807  1808
4     9   10  209  210  409  410  ...  1409  1410  1609  1610  1809  1810
..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
95  191  192  391  392  591  592  ...  1591  1592  1791  1792  1991  1992
96  193  194  393  394  593  594  ...  1593  1594  1793  1794  1993  1994
97  195  196  395  396  595  596  ...  1595  1596  1795  1796  1995  1996
98  197  198  397  398  597  598  ...  1597  1598  1797  1798  1997  1998
99  199  200  399  400  599  600  ...  1599  1600  1799  1800  1999  2000

[100 rows x 20 columns]
```